# GitHub files have been randomly deleted. Even from old commits. Why?

Tags: xcode, git, github, version-control

So I've been working on an iOS project in Xcode and have been using the built in methods to commit and push. For the whole time I've been working on this project, I've only ever pushed a WORKING version.

So, imagine how shocked I was when one morning I want to start working on my project, and I can't build it. I looked at my files and apparently four files were randomly deleted.

- And even more strange, switching to another OLDER working version still has those files DELETED.
- Checking current and older versions on GitHub and those files are NOWHERE to be found.
- I can't build my project until I switch to a really old version of the project before those files were ever added.
- I've added so much more to the project since those commits so working from back then would be like going from version 10 to version 2.

Just what has happened?? It's like those specific files have been wiped from existence. Switching to old versions on Xcode and viewing old versions GitHub reveal nothing. The files are just gone.

How could this have happened?

Comment: Are you the only person with access to the repo? Would these files be of a nature subject to a DMCA takedown; copyrighted videos, for example?

Comment: Yes, it's my own personal project. Just a weather app built using SwiftUI. I built it solo on Xcode

Comment: "I can't build my project until I switch to a really old version of the project before those files were ever added." Does this mean you should be able to find the commit where the files were added? If yes, then you should also be able to find the commit where the files were deleted.

Comment: My gut feeling here is you never committed those 4 files and maybe they were just hanging around on your system, until now. Possibly they were not committed due to being in `.gitignore`.

Comment: The thing is, I've made many more commits since I added those files and they were always there. In fact, I even have a commit specifically for the introduction of those files. But switching to it shows nothing. My latest commit and push was 3 days ago and it was working fine. Because I only commit/push if I can run the app on my phone. But now suddenly, the file titles are red in Xcode and non existent on GitHub.

Comment: Try `git show <commit-id-where-you-added-the-files> --name-only` to see if they were really added by that commit.

Comment: Is your repository in a directory managed by a cloud syncing service (e.g., iCloud or Dropbox)?  Is it otherwise on an unusual file system of any type, like a network file system?

Comment: Deleting files from commits is impossible.... you would need to get a new commit to be able to do that..... unless, of course, you deleted the blob objects and then you **busted** the original commit.

Comment: I've run ```git show``` and I don't see the files. So that means they weren't added. That's strange. So the files were never being updated with git I'm guessing. Even though I commit and push. But I wonder why it chose now to suddenly disappear from my project